# Passing a field as Update Parameter

Tags: asp.net

I want to pass a field value as update parameter of ObjectDataSource but this field is not presented in the viewing control:
Here is the code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceCurrentItem" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetItemByID" 
    InsertMethod="InsertItem" UpdateMethod="UpdateItem" TypeName="Item">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewCurrentItem" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" Height="50px" Width="50%" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceCurrentItem" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DefaultMode="Insert"
    OnItemInserted="DetailsViewCurrentItem_ItemInserted"
    OnItemUpdated="DetailsViewCurrentItem_ItemUpdated" OnItemCommand="DetailsViewCurrentItem_ItemCommand">
    <FieldHeaderStyle Width="100px" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataField="Title" 
            SortExpression="Title" ControlStyle-Width="45%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" SortExpression="Description"
             ControlStyle-Width="45%" />
        <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataField="URL" 
            SortExpression="URL" ControlStyle-Width="45%"  />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

the type "Item" has another field "Version" not presented in the DetailsView
which I want to pass to the "ObjectDataSourceCurrentItem" as an UpdateParameter
how to do this?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceCurrentItem" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetItemByID" 
    InsertMethod="InsertItem" UpdateMethod="UpdateItem" TypeName="Item">
<UpdateParameters>
             <%--past here your update parameter--%>
</UpdateParameters>  
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewCurrentItem" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" Height="50px" Width="50%" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceCurrentItem" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DefaultMode="Insert"
    OnItemInserted="DetailsViewCurrentItem_ItemInserted"
    OnItemUpdated="DetailsViewCurrentItem_ItemUpdated" OnItemCommand="DetailsViewCurrentItem_ItemCommand">
    <FieldHeaderStyle Width="100px" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataField="Title" 
            SortExpression="Title" ControlStyle-Width="45%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" SortExpression="Description"
             ControlStyle-Width="45%" />
        <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataField="URL" 
            SortExpression="URL" ControlStyle-Width="45%"  />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```